# Trying to add additional contact fields to OSCLASS contact publisher section

Tags: osclass

I've been trying to add additional label fields to the Contact Publisher section of OSCLASS Classifieds. I've tried everything and when I add the line of code in the item.php script I get an "Undefined error" The custom fields that are part of the admin panel only works with the ads themselves. This issue is with the contact publisher section on each ad. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: What code are you adding that after doing it you get an **Undefined error**?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the photo profile plugin and add the custom fields into it.